# System.DirectoryServices pegs my processor when multi-threaded - can I lower the burden?

Tags: vb.net, optimization, active-directory, directoryservices

My application takes the currently logged-in user and uses an a DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher to pull a few additional detail about them (some properties we have stored in a few custom AD fields, as well as their email address). This works great, though I've always though it was a little slow - my single-threaded code could only make about 2-3 requests/second to AD.

The real problem came when I moved this code to a web server. With multiple simultaneous users, the number of requests/second jumps greatly, and the LSASS.EXE process pegs on my server. I've checked the domain controllers, and they're just fine - the bottleneck is clearly on the application side. I suspect that what's slowing my down is the NTLM/Kerberos challenge/response, and the number of simultaneous requests pegs even the multi-core processor.

Our network policy doesn't allow anonymous reads from AD, so that choice is out. Also, I've tried every member of "AuthenticationTypes" (in the example, I'm using .FastBind), but they all seem to have about the same throughput rate with the same load on the processor.

**Does anybody have an idea for how I might work around this restriction and lower my demands on the processor?**

Here is the code I'm using - pretty straightforward:

```
Dim sPath As String = "LDAP://" & stringUserDN
Dim entry As New DirectoryEntry(sPath)
entry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.FastBind

For Each stringADNumber As String In entry.Properties(_ADPROP_EMPLOYEENUMBER)
    'return first item
    Return Convert.ToInt32(stringADNumber)
Next

Return String.Empty
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a ton of experience with looking up items in AD.  However, one suggestion is that you might want to check in the HttpContext for the request.  There is some basic information for the current user that is making the request, such as groups, SID, and token information.  I don't beleive there is an email address field by default, but you might be able to use the `User.Name` property `+ "@your.domain"` to build an email address.

In order for this data to show up, you will need IIS to be requiring authentication for requests.  Anonymous users will not have this data populated.  The accessor for this data is `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity` or, alternatively, within the code behind for your page, you can call `this.Request.LogonUserIdentity` for short.

Hopefully this helps.  Good luck.